# Is avc1.4d0128,mp4a.40.2 supported by the chromecast?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to play an m3u8 on the Chromecast but I get the following error:

error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.PLAYBACK/110 (Failed to execute 'addSourceBuffer' on 'MediaSource': The type provided ('video/mp2t; codecs="avc1.4d0128,mp4a.40.2"') is unsupported.

Is this supposed to be supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=609), some builds of Chromecast were rejected so it is recommended to use "avc1.66.30" instead. Try updating the playlist or using host.processManifest as another workaround. You can also check on this related [forum](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=398).